# moveViewToX not working with rightAxis.enabled in charts-ios

Tags: ios, charts

I'm using the excellent [Charts library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts), and have rendered a chart as follows (in `viewDidLoad`) in order to show a series of data, initially zoomed to to the last seven entries.

```
dataEntries = Array(0...60).map{ x in
        return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: Double.random(in: 1..<10))
    }
    let dataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries)
    let data = LineChartData(dataSets: [dataSet])
    myView.data = data
    myView.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: 7.0, maxXRange: 7.0)
    myView.moveViewToX(53)
    //myView.rightAxis.enabled = false
```

[It works beautifully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCjd4.png), but I wish to hide the right access. If I uncomment `myView.rightAxis.enabled = false`, the initial range [is incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRK3A.png).

Any advice anyone could give would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        dataEntries = Array(0...60).map{ x in
        return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: Double.random(in: 1..<10))
    }
    let dataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries)
    let data = LineChartData(dataSets: [dataSet])
    myView.data = data
    myView.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: 7.0, maxXRange: 7.0)
    myView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    myView.resetViewPortOffsets()
    myView.moveViewToX(53)
```

Sorted it in the end. I had to call `resetViewPortOffsets()` after disabling the right axis.